# Why is my return empty from jQuery to Velocity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity, confluence

I am working on an add-on for Confluence. I am using Apache Velocity and Js. 
When I print out my template, I get no return from my JS file where I am using jQuery. How can I establish the communication between those two correctly? Thank you!

## My JS

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var initmyConfluenceMacro = function ()
    {
        $(".myConfluenceMacro").each(function()
        {
            var html = "wadup"; 
            var dayDates = $(this).find("input.dayDates").val();
            html = html + dayDates;
            $(this).html(html);
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        initmyConfluenceMacro();
    });
});
```

## MY Velocity Template.vm

```
#requireResource("confluence.web.resources:jquery")
#requireResource("com.atlassian.tutorial.myConfluenceMacro:myConfluenceMacro-resources")

My variables : $myCustomVar
My variable js: 

<div class="myConfluenceMacro">
    <fieldset class="parameters hidden">
            <input type="hidden" class="dayDates" value="YO! Was up dude?">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no reason to nest a `$(document).ready()` setup when you're already inside a "ready" handler.

Comment: @Pointy making sure it is really ready

Comment: You need to debug and find out why it is not being found. My guess is something gets loaded dynamically and you are trying to look for it before it is on the page. console.log and debugger are your friend.

Comment: @epascarello Actually I want to pass the value from .vm to js. The value is already set. But still, I get nothing back. Is there maybe a better way to establish communication between .js and .vm? I can't find any good example where I can see the transfer of variables on both sides.

Comment: Well one thing you can to do investigate is `console.log($(".myConfluenceMacro").length)` before the `.each()` call. That'll tell you if the DOM contains any instances of the macro contents after expansion.

Comment: @Pointy I tried this: $(document).ready(function()
    {
  var html = "I AM HERE"; 
  $(this).html(html);
        //initmyConfluenceMacro();
    }); and I still get nothing :(

Comment: @Pointy I can't see the log file :( It is not my confluence instance, so I don't have access to the log. I can only upload the jar directly and see the result...

Comment: Are you viewing the resulting content in a browser? That's where `console.log()` goes.

Comment: Oh thank you! @Pointy I was always opening a log file and looking. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Pointy The error message I get is: "Error running batched script"

Comment: Well if your script has some sort of error in it, that would certainly explain why it doesn't seem to work. JavaScript errors can be a little obtuse but the error should tell you exactly what it thinks is wrong: syntax error, exception, whatever; and also where in the code the error happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it. Like this, it is working, and I get the HTML back!

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myConfluenceMacro").each(function(){
        $(this).html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
    });
});
```

## VELOCITY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 #include( "templates/currencyDetail.js")
</script>
<body>

<div class="myConfluenceMacro">

</div>
```